# Inheritance for controller and service classes in a spring project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, service, controller

In my current spring project, my controller and service classes have similar structures. I want then create a base class for both of them, which will be used as base for all the other controller and service classes. Anyone can tell me if this is possible?

The basic structure for this classes are (the term <> will vary):

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="<<name>>")
public class <<name>>Controler {

    @Autowired
    private <<name>>Service <<name>>;

    @RequestMapping(value="cadastra.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_<<name>>')")
    public String cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if(<<name>>.cadastra(request, response))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "not";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="altera.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_<<name>>')")
    public String altera(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if(<<name>>.altera(request, response))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "not";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="remove.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'remove_<<name>>')")
    public String remove(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if(<<name>>.remove(request, response))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "not";
    }

}
```

**service**

```
@Service
public class <<name>>Service {

    @Autowired
    private <<name>>Dao <<name>>;

    public boolean cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return <<name>>.persist(null);
    }

    public boolean altera(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return <<name>>.merge(null);
    }

    public boolean remove(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return <<name>>.remove(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring framework does not restrict you to use usual java `extends` clause. 
Superclass instance may even be a bean itself.
Or maybe I did not understand your question ?

Comment: My question is, if I extend a controller ou service class, how I customize values for the mapping or used by hasPermission, by example?

Comment: I wish find a solution that allow me do the same I am doing with my Dao classes, which are like this: https://github.com/klebermo/webcms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/webapp/lojavirtual/acesso/persistence/UsuarioHome.java

Comment: Annotations cannot be overriden from superclass separately, so you are forced to override full methods and their annotations.

But you may try using uri template with regular expressions (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) in superclass and call overriden (descendant) method.

Comment: About `hasPermission`, try to use same `#` syntax for permission, as you did for object (`#user`).